CORS - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check - Nitro Server
Am working on an application with Vue JS has frontend and Nitro JS has backend. I have the below configuration in nitro.config.ts
//https://nitro.unjs.io/config
export default defineNitroConfig({
  srcDir: "server",    
  routeRules:{
    '/api/**': { cors: true, headers: {'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE','access-control-allow-origin':'http://localhost:5173','access-control-allow-headers':'Content-Type,Authorization' } },
  }
  
});


But still I get the CORS error.
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/api/booking' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

This is only happening for POST method, GET seems to be working fine.
Initially it was throwing CORS error for GET and POST as well. After I added the above config to nitro.config.ts the original error is gone. The OPTIONS is also added to CORS allowed post config. Still the same error.

the problem in your case is at the very end. "It does not have HTTP ok status" check the response to your OPTIONS request in your browser. it should be empty, and 200 or 204

Thanks for that. It made me realize I don't have a booking.options.ts that returns "success". Once I added it, it got fixed. Sorry, am new to Nitro.
